# how can you get a content of a folder with a stream in java?

Tags: java, stream, fileinputstream

I'm trying to create my own stream, something like a `PathContentStream`, that gets a path and returns how many files, folders, and sub-folders are in it and what type they are (like avi or txt).

Is there anything in the java streams API that would be useful to implement this?

Comment: What is the end goal of this? How would this be used? And why do you want to stream it?

Comment: file type based on what? a (Windows) three char extension? file type is tricky, not sure there is any generic cross platform way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear what will be an essense of such stream. General answer: **no, there is not such streams in java api**. But if you will compose the essense of it, you can create your own, which will implement something like:

```
public interface InputFileItemStream implements Closeable {

     File read();
     void close();
     void reset();
     ...
}
```